# MatchIt with more than one unit

Tags: r, matching

I want to use `MatchIt` on a data set with one treated unit and `N` number of control units. (control and treated does not matter for me, I can call the `N` samples treated and the unique one as control.)

I want to sort the `N` samples according to their distance from the control units.

Simply I want to sort the control samples according to their distance from the unique treated sample.

How can I do this? What is the argument that determines the number of matches?

the `matchit(formula, data, method)` is just giving me one match.

Thanks

Comment: It could be rewarding to look into the [`Matching`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/index.html) package, I made better experiences with it.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is `ratio`; for example, to do variable 2:1 matching, you would set `ratio = 2`. There are some bugs that makes this not work for all matching methods.